# How to search by fullName field in OpenSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have an index in OpenSearch which contains documents like this:

```
{
  "employee": {
    "id": "4",
    "fullName": "Ivanov Ivan Ivanovich"
  }
}
```

I want to create a query which can search me documents by fullName field in way like this: "Ivanov Ivan" or "Ivanov I I".

Let's assume that index contains this documents:

```
{
  "employee": {
    "id": "4",
    "fullName": "Ivanov Ivan Ivanovich"
  }
},
{
  "employee": {
    "id": "5",
    "fullName": "Ivanov Gleb Glebovich"
  }
}
```

I wrote this query:

```
GET /contact/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "employee.fullName": "Ivanov"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "employee.fullName": "Ivan"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I expect to get a single result of
`"fullName": "Ivanov Ivan Ivanovich"`

But it returns me both results where fullNames are:

`"fullName": "Ivanov Ivan Ivanovich"`

`"fullName": "Ivanov Gleb Glebovich"`

It happens because both of these results contain "Ivan" as a part of first "Ivanov".

Is there a way to modify my query to specify that order of appearance is important?

This application is just a phone book and I want to allow users to search contacts just specifying second name and two first letters of last name and second name.